# How do I factor a polynomial raised to the power of $l$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

> Given: $(x^2-1)^l$

I need to factor this to return $(x+1)^l(x-1)^l$. I tried binomial expansion on both the given polynomial and the first term of the answer, but I can't make a connection as to what I need to do next. I feel like a binomial expansion is not the right way to go.

Screenshot of the problem from the book, Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences, Mary Boas:

[image]

Comment: No, $(x^2-1)^\ell=(x+1)^\ell(x-1)^\ell$.

Comment: Ah, it must be a typo in the book then. See the screenshot I've added. This book is full of typos.

Comment: Yes, that’s a typo: someone confused non-script lower-case $\ell$ with the digit $1$. (That’s why I always use $\ell$ instead of $l$ in mathematical expressions.)

Comment: They use $l$ in this book. Makes it hard to differentiate between that and a $1$ on a mobile device.